# Asynchronous HTTP call inside HTTP cycle of Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, python-asyncio

I need to call external service on the get_queryset function of one of my viewsets on views.py, but I don't need to wait for the response of external function.

How can I make the following requests.post line just triggered and passed to next line without waiting for the result?

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        ....
        requests.post(urlOfApi+token)
        .....
        return Some.objects.all()
```

Comment: Try to write [celery task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), and make the external API request through celery

Comment: is it the simplest method?

Comment: or you can use [threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I implemented an endpoint to run a background task. When you hit the `post` the endpoint returns the id of the job. Then you can hit the `get` endpoint with the job task id and you get back the result or `in progress` if the job is still running.

I didn't use `celery` to accomplish this task, but [django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that I found easier than celery and moreover django-q uses all the batteries django has already. Here an example of API View I implemented with django-q.

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django_q.models import Task, OrmQ
from django_q.tasks import async, result
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


def the_function_to_run():
    # do something here
    pass


class YourTaskApiView(APIView):

    def get(self):

        # you mustr construct the get url to take the id
        task_id = self.kwargs.get('task_id')

        try:
            task = Task.objects.get(id=task_id)
        except Task.DoesNotExist:
            task = None

        # here the task is on processing
        if task:
            return Response({
                'id': task_id,
                'result': result(task_id),
                'started': task.started,
                'stopped': task.stopped,
                'status': 'DONE' if task.stopped else 'RUNNING',
                'success': task.success,
            })
        else:
            # here you find the task in the query (not even processed, but waiting for the cluster to process it)
            for q in OrmQ.objects.all():
                if q.task_id() == task_id:
                    task = q.task()
                    return Response({
                        'id': task['id'],
                        'started': task['started'],
                        'status': 'WAITING', # or ON QUEUE
                        'stopped': None,
                        'success': None,
                    })

        return NotFound()


    def post(self, request):

        # run the task as async
        task_id = async(the_function_to_run)

        # create the reverse for the get so the client already has the link to query for
        # the task status
        link = reverse('yourapp:yournamespace:yourview', kwargs={'task_id': task_id}, request=request)
        return Response(data={'task_id': task_id, 'link': link})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some kind of background jobs for this kind of work.

As mentioned in the comment - one way is to use celery.

If you don't want to go through that way. You can try the following:

https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Perhaps, not as powerful as the celery way, but easier to setup and run.

You simply implement a function to perform the work ( in your case, making http request to another service) , decorate it with background decorator. 
And then, in your viewset, you simple call the function and it will be scheduled. You can even choose the time when.